# XSLT : transform flat XML to hierarchic XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new with xml, it's very difficult for me to understand how XSLT works.
Can you help me fix some errors in my xslt file?
I'd like to transform this input file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <parent><string >AAA</string></parent>
    <nb><string >2</string></nb>
    <child1>aaa-1</child1>
    <child1>aaa-2</child1>
    <parent><string >BBB</string></parent>
    <nb><string>1</string></nb>
    <child2>bbb-1</child2>
    <parent><string >CCC</string></parent>
    <nb><string >0</string></nb>
</data>
```

into :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <parent>
        <string >AAA</string>
        <nb><string >2</string></nb>
        <child1>aaa-1</child1>
        <child1>aaa-2</child1></parent>
    <parent>
        <string >BBB</string>
        <nb><string >1</string></nb>
        <child2>bbb-1</child2></parent>
    <parent>
        <string >CCC</string>
        <nb><string >0</string></nb></parent>
</data>
```

The rules are :

1. The "nb" node indicates the number of childs for each parent. It can
   be 0.
2. The nodes "child1" and "child2" are different. They are complex,
   with    nested loops etc. My above input file is simplified for demo. 
   I 
       think,    I've to use the 'copy' instruction.
3. What is difficult for me, is that :

   - for each parent, I've to read the defined number ("nb") of child nodes following  current parent
   - when the "parent" value is 'AAA' then I've to read the "child1" 
     when the "parent" value is !=AAAA then I've to read the "childe2" node.

Here is my XSLT file, the result is not exactly as expected :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:comment>--- </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:comment>1 : parent nodes </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:for-each select ="/data/parent">
            <p> 
                <string>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string"/>
                </string>
                <xsl:comment>======================= </xsl:comment>
                <xsl:comment>2 : nb nodes (how many childs for a parent ) </xsl:comment>
                <xsl:for-each select ="/data/nb">
                    <xsl:if test="((position() &lt; 2) and (normalize-space(position() &gt;= 1)))">
                        <xsl:comment>Ex. for tThe first value only </xsl:comment>
                        <xsl:comment>How to do a dynamic test here (expected : AAA->3 (first nb value), BBB->1 (second nb value) ...)  ?</xsl:comment>
                        <xsl:comment>How to synchronise loop on parent and nb  ?</xsl:comment>
                        <nb>
                            <string>
                                <xsl:value-of select="string"/>
                            </string>
                        </nb>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:comment>======================= </xsl:comment>
                <xsl:comment>3 : child nodes </xsl:comment>
                <xsl:comment>How to manage the position and number of nodes to read ?</xsl:comment>
                <xsl:comment>Test 'string =AAA' is KO : always child2 </xsl:comment>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test='string =AAA'>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/*/child1" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/*/child2" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>               
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Sorry, it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is consistent, that is, if there is always the number of `child1/child2` elements the `nb` element indicates and the `parent` value mandates then you can simply process the different types of `parent` elements with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="parent"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[string = 'AAA']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="n" select="following-sibling::nb[1]"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="string, following-sibling::nb[1], following-sibling::child1[position() &lt;= $n]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[string != 'AAA']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="n" select="following-sibling::nb[1]"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="string, following-sibling::nb[1], following-sibling::child2[position() &lt;= $n]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzk/0 has that sample, you could as well do that in XSLT 1 as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="parent"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[string = 'AAA']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="n" select="following-sibling::nb[1]"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="string | following-sibling::nb[1] | following-sibling::child1[position() &lt;= $n]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[string != 'AAA']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="n" select="following-sibling::nb[1]"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="string | following-sibling::nb[1] | following-sibling::child2[position() &lt;= $n]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzk/1

If the data is not consistent then at least in XSLT 2 or 3 it would be an easy job for `for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="parent"` in the context of the `data` element to identify the elements that belong together and create the `parent` wrapper in the result.

Comment: Great answer Martin, it works fine. **Thanks à lot**

Comment: The code makes a deep copy with e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="string | following-sibling::nb[1] | following-sibling::child2[position() &lt;= $n]"/>`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzk/2, so the elements including their content should be copied. Ask a new question with the details of what you have changed if you can't work it out.

Comment: Yes, it works well.  Just a litle question :   why it doesn't work when the root line **<data>** contains : **<data xmlns="http://www.aspzone.com/xml/serialization">**?

Comment: I tried to add a name space : xmlns:ser="http://www.aspzone.com/xml/serialization" into slt file. But when I prefix all nodes in the slt file with   **ser:**,  it works only for nb node, the child1 and child2 nodes are not retrieved. Why does it fail ?

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 3.0 this is simply

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <data>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="parent">
        <parent>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*, tail(current-group())"/>
        </parent>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I have an error message during the test with ETL Talend XSLT component (java):
`Error at xsl:copy-of on line 7 column 59 of exemple1b_slt30_solution2.xsl:
  XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 24 on line 7 in {*, tail(current-group())}:
    Unknown system function tail()
Exception in component tXSLT_4
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
 at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:176)
 at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates
`   Thanks a lot  Best regards

Comment: Installing xsltproc is complicated, can you suggest me another way to test your solution please ?

Comment: @asx, to use XSLT 3 with Java you can use any edition of Saxon 9.8, the open-source HE edition is available on Sourceforge and Maven.

Comment: @asx those error messages look as if they are coming from Saxon, but from a version of Saxon that does not support XSLT 3.0. Check you are using the latest version of Saxon (9.8.0.x). Alternatively the `tail(x)` function can be rewritten `remove(x, 1)` to run with an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: I installed Saxon-HE-9.8.0-12.jar instead of saxon9.jar. It always fails for the tail and remove  functions. @Martin, could you read my comment above related for XSLT name space, please ? I can't fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're clearly not invoking Saxon 9.8 then: you've got something wrong in the way you installed, configured, or invoked the transformation.